# django-easy-pdf displays no content

Tags: python, django, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to render a pdf file with **Django** using **django-easy-pdf**. I followed [these instructions](https://django-easy-pdf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.2.0-dev1/usage.html), but I get an empty pdf.

This is my html:

```
{% extends "easy_pdf/base.html" %}

{% block extra_style %}
{% endblock %}

<% block content %>
  <div id="summary-block">
    <p>Here goes that square with data.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="declarations-block">
    <p>Here goes the Main content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="data-block">
    <p>Here goes all the data from the contract.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="clause-block">
    <p>Here goes the Clause content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="signatures-block">
    <p>Here goes the signatures content.</p>
  </div>
<% endblock %>
```

And this is my `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from easy_pdf.views import PDFTemplateView

# Create your views here.
class ContractPDFView(PDFTemplateView):
    template_name = 'contract.html'

    base_url = 'file://' + settings.TEMPLATES_DIR
    download_filename = 'contract.pdf'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return super(ContractPDFView, self).get_context_data(pagesize='letter', title='Contract', **kwargs)
```

I don't know what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer is a bit late - your mistake is that you mix <> and {} in your template.

Instead of

```
<% block content %><% endblock content %>
```

it should be

```
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}.
```